# Elmah: Not showing Exceptions on Testing Environment

Tags: c#-4.0, model-view-controller, elmah, elmah.mvc

Elmah is logging the Errors(in specified path) but not showing on the interface "elmah.axd".
and it is working fine on the local enviromnent.

Please guide me. I am new for elmah.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you didn't enable remote access to elmah.axd. please take a look through this [ELMAH security guide](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-security-and-allowremoteaccess-explained/).

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for your reply, could you please let me know that when i  enable the flag then prior to enabling that flag all exception(which occurred prior to enabling flag) will be shown on the interface or not. because it is not showing and after enabling I have not faced any exception.

Comment: Setting the allowRemoteAccess to true doesn't change anything when logging exceptions. It's a flag telling ELMAH, if /elmah.axd should be accesible on other than localhost only. I wouldn't recommend you to allow remote access though. Would make your log public to the world.

Comment: Hi Thomas, i have updated the allowRemoteAccess=true but still i am not able to see the exceptions list on the "elmah.axd" interface Is something i am doing wrong? It is working on the local and agree with your concern you raised thanks for that

Comment: That's weird. Do you see the ELMAH UI with an empty list or is the request to /elmah.axd returning af 404?

Comment: Sounds like you have something else when running in release build that swallows all exceptions. Could also be that some of your web.config are transformed wrong on release build. If you could share your web.config and web.release.config, it would be a help for sure.

Comment: sorry Thomas i won't be able to share the webconfig,it would be great if you could tell me any lead/input to trace the issue which you want to look into web config.

Comment: I would start by validating it here: https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, you gave me direction and based on your inputs/direction my problem is resolved thanks once again

Comment: that was just typo sorry for the late response